# Azure DevOps Template recommendation for Node.js and Java projects

Tags: azure-devops

Can someone help me with choosing a TEMPLATE for Azure DevOps Porject for Build and Release pipeline. For Release pipeline it is very easy as I can chose the Azure App Service Deploy Template and it works but for Build is something that I would like a recommendation instead of modifying the yml file with tasks. Any recommendations? for Asp.Net projects I do see there is ASP.Net (Core) template but I need something similar for Node.js any help?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for Asp.Net projects I do see there is ASP.Net (Core) template but I need something similar for Node.js any help?

You can try to use the template `Node.js With gulp` or `Node.js With Grunt` to build the Node.js project:

[image]

Check the document [Publish a Node.js application in Azure environment using VSTS and CI / CD](https://medium.com/@rafaelmbs/publish-a-node-js-application-in-azure-environment-using-vsts-and-ci-cd-18fad9838577) for more details.

Hope this helps.